# File sync between n web servers in cluster

Tags: go, synchronization, consul

There are *n* nodes in a web cluster.  Files may be uploaded to any node and then must be distributed to every other node. This distribution does not have to happen in a transaction (in fact it must not, distributed transactions don't scale) and some latency is acceptable, although must be minimal.  Conflicts can be resolved arbitrarily (typically last write wins) provided that the resolution is also distributed to all nodes so that eventually all nodes have the same set of files.  Nodes can be added and removed dynamically without having to reconfigure existing nodes.  There must be no single point of failure and no additional boxes required to solve this (such as RabbitMQ)

I am thinking along the lines of using consul.io for dynamic configuration so that each node can refer to consul to determine what other nodes are available and writing a daemon (Golang) that monitors the relevant folders and communicates with other nodes using ZeroMQ.

Feels like I would be re-inventing the wheel though.  This is a common problem and I expect there are solutions available already that I don't know about? Or perhaps my approach is wrong and there is another way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there has been some stuff going on with distributed synchronization lately:

You could use [syncthing](https://syncthing.net) (open source) or [BitTorrent Sync](https://www.getsync.com).

Syncthing is node-based, i.e. you add nodes to a cluster and choose which folders to synchronize.

BTSync is folder-based, i.e. you obtain a "secret" for a folder and can synchronize with everyone in the swarm for that folder.

From my experience, BTSync has a better discovery and connectivity, but the whole synchronization process is closed source and nobody really knows what happens. Syncthing is written in go, but sometimes has trouble discovering peers.

Both syncthing and BTSync use LAN discovery via broadcast and a tracker for discovery, AFAIK.

**EDIT**: Or, if you're really cool, use IPFS to host the latest version, IPNS to "name" that and mount the IPNS on the servers. You can set the IPFS bootstrap list to some of your servers, which would even make you independent of external trackers. :)